# Помогите ускорить QEMU на Windows

Tags: qemu

Проблемы с QEMU. Мне нужно запустить виртуалку с флешки. VMWare пишет ошибку доступа к флешке, а в VirtualBox такой возможноти в принципе нет. Поэтому пришлось скачать QEMU.

Я запускаю этой командой:

`qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -hdb \\.\PhysicalDrive2 -no-acpi -cpu athlon -enable-kvm`

Но работает **ДИКО** медленно!

P.S. Флешка не медленная